# how to extend optional chaining for all types

Tags: swift

If we have optional values `foo` and `bar`, Swift will allow us to write:

```swift
foo?.doSomething(bar)
```

Which will evaluate to `nil` if `foo` is `nil`. But it will not let us write:

```swift
foo?.doSomething(bar?)
```

That is, optional chaining only works on the arguments outside a function call, not inside the argument list. (The reasons for this limitation are unclear, but here we are.)

Suppose I want to write an `apply` function that lets me move things into the jurisidiction of optional chaining, like so:

```swift
bar?.apply { foo?.doSomething($0) }
```

Here, `apply` is a generic function that takes one argument (in this case `bar`) and then executes the closure. So if either `foo` or `bar` is nil, the expression will be `nil`.

Here's what I’ve tried:

```swift
public protocol HasApply {}
extension HasApply {
    public func apply<T>(_ f : (Self) -> T) -> T {
        f(self)
    }
}
```

That’s fine as far as it goes. But to make it work, I still have to explicitly apply the protocol to the types I care about:

```swift
extension Int : HasApply {}
```

OK, that makes it work with `Int`. But I don’t want to copy & paste for every type. So I try this:

```swift
extension AnyObject : HasApply {}
```

No, that won’t work: the error is `Non-nominal type 'AnyObject' cannot be extended`.

Hence the question: **is there no way to make this generic function work as a protocol method?**

Comment: There isn't, it's a special form built for `Optional`, with no protocol for extensibility from Swift code.

Comment: Regarding your `AnyObject` attempt what you are looking for is `extension NSObject: HasApply { }`

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but instead of making all types conform to your custom protocol `HasApply`  you can simply extend an existing protocol that most types conforms to such as `CVarArg` Protocol `extension CVarArg {
    func apply<T>(_ f : (Self) -> T) -> T {
        f(self)
    }
}` this would work with most Swift types

Comment: `CVarArg` seems to work for simple values like `Int` or `String`, but not for a class instance … ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there no way to make this generic function work as a protocol method?

No, you must "explicitly apply the protocol to the types I care about".

However, you are in fact reinventing the wheel. This is the use case of [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap)/[`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map). If both `foo` and `bar` are optional, you can write:

```
bar.flatMap { foo?.doSomething($0) }
```

Note the lack of `?` after `bar`. You are calling `flatMap` on `Optional`, rather than `bar`'s type. If `doSomething` returns `T`, the above expression will return `T?`.

If only `bar` is optional, use `map`:

```
bar.map { foo.doSomething($0) }
```

Comment: True, but only for iterable types that support `map` and `flatMap`. As for other types, I think the question stands.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. That is a very strange way to overload `map` and `flatMap`.

Comment: @MatthewButterick it’s not strange, if you think of `flatMap` as the name for the monadic operator (IIRC it’s called `bind`/`>>=` in other languages). Optionals and sequences are both monads. (Note that this is not part of Swift’s type system, but the API designers clearly had monads in mind when naming things)

Answer (score 1):

As Sweeper pointed out, the language already provides you the tool for this, in the form of the `map`/`flatMap` functions.

But you could also write

```swift
if let foo = foo, let bar = bar {
    foo.doSomething(bar)
}
```

This is an easier to read, understand, and maintain code, with clearly transmits the intent: you want `doSomething` to be called if both the receiver of the call and its argument are non-nil.

---

Now, why it would not be a good idea for the language to have this feature built-in - it's due to the way the compiler processes the code: from left to right.

The optional chaining is a short-circuit operator, thus

```swift
foo?.someExpensiveComputation().doSomething(bar)
```

will stop at runtime as soon as it detects that `foo` is nil. Which means that `someExpensiveComputation` will not be executed. Not the same thing can be said about a construct like this:

```swift
foo?.someExpensiveComputation().doSomething(bar?)
```

Assuming `foo` is not nil, but `bar` is nil, the program will execute `someExpensiveComputation` just to find out that `doSomething` doesn't need execution. Thus, the short-circuit no longer applies.

Let's take another example, let's assume `doSomething` has two parameters:

```swift
foo?.doSomething(someExpensiveComputation(), bar)
```

Again, the compiler evaluates from left to right, thus the expensive computation will be performed, just to be thrown away once the program detects at runtime that the second argument is nil.

Now, yes, the compiler might implement some advanced heuristics of looking ahead for possible nil values, but this would be highly complicated and would add lots of performance penalties at runtime.

The bottom line, the compiler will provide you with short-circuits, as long as those are well-behaved, predictable, and don't overwhelm the compiler.